# EPPlus Shape Lines and Connectors

Tags: c#, epplus

I don't see functionality in EPPlus to read lines with respective connectors to other shapes.  Is this feature missing?  If so, what alternatives are there?  Can I go straight into the xml and try and determine the connectors?

I see "To" and "From" properties in the line shape but the underlying info is not much understandable to me.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out using XML

```
    var drawingsXML = ws_plants.Drawings.DrawingXml;
    var connectionNodes = drawingsXML.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='nvCxnSpPr']");

    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode cn in connectionNodes)
    {
        var nameNode = cn.SelectNodes("*[local-name()='cNvPr']");
        string name = nameNode[0].Attributes["name"].Value;

        var connectorsNode = cn.SelectNodes("*[local-name()='cNvCxnSpPr']");

        var startConnectionNode = connectorsNode[0].SelectNodes("*[local-name()='stCxn']");
        string startId = startConnectionNode[0].Attributes["id"].Value;

        var endConnectionNode = connectorsNode[0].SelectNodes("*[local-name()='endCxn']");
        string endId = endConnectionNode[0].Attributes["id"].Value;

    }
```